# MySQL Truncate function giving incorrect result on some entries

Tags: mysql

I want to perform some calculation from my table, with query

```
SELECT foo.idop, foo.cost, foo.qty, foo.rate, TRUNCATE(((foo.cost * foo.qty * foo.rate) / 100),2) AS charge FROM table_foobar foo;
```

This query is working totally fine, and giving expected results for most of records. But some records are giving results with -0.01 deviation.

I have huge amounts of data, and I'm unable to understand the strange behavior of this `TRUNCATE()` function.

Please check below screenshot for some sample entries, where highlighted rows are giving an incorrect result.

[image]

Comment: What data types do the columns have? Are some `float`? Maybe you need to cast some of them to `decimal`.

Comment: @juergend better yet, change the schema.

Comment: @BartFriederichs and juergend both options are working. Thanks a lot. I took shortcut & changed schema

Comment: @juergend u Rocked. Changing schema resulted to some fractional data loss.